# Plugin jQuery,div animate with background on full resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

ciao, esiste un plugin per questo effetto?
provate a cliccare su una qualsiasi sezione del menu, il div si anima
grazie

sito di esempio
http://planetpropaganda.com/

hello, there is a plugin for this effect?
try to click on any section of the menu, the div is animated
thanks

sample site
http://planetpropaganda.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plenty of plugins for this.

You can try this one - http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Or this one - http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/#/Home

Both libraries will do the job.